# て form and number, what does it mean example: "ザーレスが滅んで千年"

Tags: grammar, て-form

Sentence:

> それがサングルド山脈のどこかにあるというのだが、ザーレスが滅んで千年、いまだに入り口すら見つかっていないのだ。

Is it "...after destruction of ザーレス thousand years passed, and even now..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is precisely as you stated.

> 「Verb in て/で-form + time period」

means:

> "(It has been) N weeks/months/years/centuries ***since*** (event described by the verb phrase)"

***Informally***, you can insert 「から」 between the て/で-form  and the time period.